# Printing a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently using this code to print google map

```
<script language="javascript">
var contents = window.opener.document.getElementById("map_container");
document.write(contents.innerHTML);
window.print();
</script>
```

The problem is that some wierd controls are showing in bottom left corner also with google copyright watermark. Here are images:
-zoom out: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/zoomoutd.png/ -zoom in: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/zoominb.png/. I dont have a problem with the control in upper right corner, but i would like to get rid of those things in the bottom. Btw if it possible to work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to be a-printing the satellite view, Google has [details here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144343). Likely, there's no supported way to do this. This questions has details on a [workaround using the static maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532234/printing-api-generated-google-maps-from-internet-explorer), so that might be an option.

Comment: Damn... I didnt know that... This guy is sayin that only way is with static Maps API URL request string from the LatLng. Do you know how should i do that? Btw is it possible to print satelitte view with static API?